# Profiling only the namespaces that I need with VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, profiling, profiler

[vsinstr.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182402(v=vs.80).aspx) has the option to include only the namespaces that needs to profile.

With this option, I could get the vsp file.

```
cl /Zi helloclass.cpp /link /Profile
vsinstr helloclass.exe /include:Fpga::*
vsperfcmd /start:trace /output:trace.vsp
helloclass
vsperfcmd /shutdown
```

However, it still contains the `std::` namespaces.

[image]

### ADDED

I tried with /exclude:std::*, and I get way too many functions including the `std::` functions.
[image]

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182402%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

`/include` doesn't accept wildcards, try using `/exclude:std::*`

EDIT: Try adding `/exclude:::__*` or `/exclude:__*` to get rid of global namespace functions starting with __. Haven't tested this, and the documentation isn't clear, but worth a try.

Comment: vs2010 and later seem to support wildcards for include:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182402.aspx

Answer (score 1):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182402%28v=vs.100%29.aspx vsinstr.exe for VS 2010 (and up to 2015) doesn't support `/include` for code coverage.
So the only way to clean the results is using `/exclude:std::*`.

You can also check what functions will be instrumented prior to instrumentation process itself and save your time by using `/dumpfuncs` option as the following:

```
vsinstr.exe /dumpfuncs /exclude:std::* /exclude:`std::* > foo.txt
```